# How do I get the type (not of a class but that) of an instance of class

Tags: c#

To get the type of a class called **myClass** I do this

```
Type myType = (typeof(myClass))
```

How about, instead of having **myClass**, I've rather the **instanceOfMyClass**? How do I get the type?

Let's say I've this

```
Contact contact = new Contact();
```

If I want to know which type is contact, how do I do it

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use `contact.GetType();` method. The `GetType` is defined in the `Object` class so is available globally.

Answer (score 2):

If I've read this correctly, you can get the run-time type of the object via:

```
Contact contact = new Contact();
Type contactType = contact.GetType();
```